# Is it possible to make UML diagram for Javascript class in PhpStorm or any Jetbrain IDE?

Tags: javascript, uml, phpstorm

Recently I was working with Object oriented JavaScript. So I wanted to generate UML diagram of my JavaScript program/classes. But found no option for doing that.

Is it possible with PhpStorm or any of JetBrains' IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2022, JavaScript and TypeScript UML diagram generation is available though plugin for JetBrains.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17380-uml-javascript-and-typescript

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not in PhpStorm/WebStorm.

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7341 -- for JavaScript
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13063 -- for TypeScript

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

Try [IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) -- it *may* support it (based on comments in first ticket) but I'm not sure on this at all.

Comment: I tried in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate - did not work.
Guys, please don't forget to vote for the above mentioned issues. 
Thanks!